# Про оформление кода в научно-исследовательских работах

Tags: стандарт, гост, оформление

Здравствуйте!

Не могу найти точного описания того, по какому стандарту нужно оформлять код в научно-исследовательских работах. Основной стандарт, описывающий оформление подобных работ — ГОСТ ДСТУ 3008-95, — дает точно понять, что код указывается в приложениях к работе, но нет ни слова, каким шрифтом (моноширинный или нет, междустрочный интервал, размер шрифта, и так далее) и нужна ли нумерация строк.

Если кто-то с этим сталкивался, буду признателен за ответ.

Comment: Мы все оформляли моноширинным 10 кеглем с однострочным интервалом.

Comment: ну или еще меньше... и, разумеется, не весь код, а только самые важные части. (его вообще кто-то читает?)